# Non-invocable member 'IUnitOfWork.AdminMerchants' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, unit-of-work

In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project, I am implementing Repository and UnitOfWork:

I have this code:

IMerchantRepository:

```
public interface IAdminMerchantRepository : IGenericRepository<Merchant>
{
    IQueryable<AllMerchantListDto> GetAllMerchantAsync(PagingFilter filter);
}
```

MerchantRepository:

```
public class AdminMerchantRepository : GenericRepository<Merchant>, IAdminMerchantRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<Merchant> _adminMerchants;
    public AdminMerchantRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _adminMerchants = _dbContext.Set<Merchant>();
    }
    public IQueryable<AllMerchantListDto> GetAllMerchantAsync(PagingFilter filter)
    {
        var merchants = _dbContext.Merchants
                        .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery) || x.User.UserName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.User.Email.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
                    || x.MerchantName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
                        .Include(x => x.User)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
        return (IQueryable<AllMerchantListDto>)merchants;
    }
}
```

IUnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IAdminMerchantRepository AdminMerchants { get; }
    Task Save();
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private IAdminMerchantRepository _adminMerchants;

    public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public IAdminMerchantRepository AdminMerchants => _adminMerchants ??= new AdminMerchantRepository(_dbContext);
    public async Task Save()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dbContext.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> Non-invocable member 'IUnitOfWork.AdminMerchants' cannot be used like a method

Then this AdminMerchants highlighted in:

> var merchant = await _unitOfWork.AdminMerchants(filter);

Comment: Apologies :P Just a quick thing for you to note, in EFCore, a DbContext is a unit of work. Also, you are missing your function named `GetAllMerchantAsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `GetAllMerchantAsync` is not async method. You need call `await _unitOfWork.AdminMerchants.GetAllMerchantAsync(filter).ToListAsync()` and better to rename method to `GetAllMerchant`.
2. Your query will fail, because you have produced not `IQueryable<AllMerchantListDto>` but `IQueryable<Merchant>`. That's why you have applied wrong explicit cast.

It should be:

```cs
return merchants.Select(m => new AllMerchantListDto
{
   ... // assign properties
});
```

3. Do not create additional abstractions if they are not needed. `DbContext` is already Unit Of Work and `DbSet` is already Repository. `GetAllMerchant` can be just extension method and no additional abstractions are needed.

Comment: I only just saw this now. I never understand some peoples naming schemes lol

Answer (score 3):

It look like you're calling 
`var merchant = await _unitOfWork.AdminMerchants(filter);` 
where you mean to be calling 
`var merchant = await _unitOfWork.AdminMerchants.GetAllMerchantAsync(filter);`.